# Unwanted Underscores appear between anchor tags (HTML)

Tags: html, tags, anchor

Im working on developing anchor tags for my website using HTML.
When I preview my code in jsfiddle I see underscores between each of the anchor tags.Why are there underscores? How can I remove them?
Here's a picture of what I mean.
Here's a link to my code
https://jsfiddle.net/Ricardoberbor/1soma26o/

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/ricardo.berumenborrego" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://s6.postimg.org/4ya8t5ce9/Facebook.png" alt="https://www.google.com.mx" style="width:42px;height:42px;border:0"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ricberbor3" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://s6.postimg.org/u6zo0k6pt/Linkedin.png" alt="https://www.google.com.mx" style="width:42px;height:42px;border:0">
</a><a href="https://www.behance.net/ricardoberbor" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://s6.postimg.org/4hp16pon5/Behance.png" alt="https://www.google.com.mx" style="width:42px;height:42px;border:0">
</a><a href="https://pinterest.com/ricardoberbor/" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://s6.postimg.org/9o4rvhssh/Pinterest.png" alt="https://www.google.com.mx" style="width:42px;height:42px;border:0">
</a><br><a href="https://www.jovoto.com/community/RicardoBerumen" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://s6.postimg.org/3kn7bl2ip/Jovoto.png" alt="https://www.google.com.mx" style="width:42px;height:42px;border:0">
</a><a href="https://www.bevisible.soy/users/10058" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://s6.postimg.org/82kwpxt6p/Be_Visible.png" alt="https://www.google.com.mx" style="width:42px;height:42px;border:0">
</a><a href="https://dribbble.com/ricardoberbor" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://s6.postimg.org/xmn6wdekh/Dribbble.png" alt="https://www.google.com.mx" style="width:42px;height:42px;border:0">
</a>`

Answer (score 2):

```
a { text-decoration: none}
```

[checkout here](https://jsfiddle.net/mukeshrana90/478nzjLd/1/)

This will solve your problem.

Comment: I'm writing this in HTML ( I'm really new to it). How would I add this to the html code? You're giving me CSS.

Comment: <style> a { text-decoration: none;} </style>

Answer (score 1):

STYLE="text-decoration: none" worked!
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be since these are URL's, it is the underline typically associated with a URL. To remove this you typically have to use text-decoration:none; in your CSS somewhere.

Normally I have a separate CSS file with a { text-decoration: none; } i'm not sure if it will work in the inline css you have there.

My suggestion would be to maybe have separate URL styles for images:

img a { text-decoration: none }

Comment: I'm writing this in HTML ( I'm really new to it). How would I add this to the html code? You're giving me CSS.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1soma26o/10/#&togetherjs=Fb1PcRtopu I added some CSS in the page you linked.

Comment: link is being wierd, anyway. Add this to theCSS in the top right a { text-decoration: none; }

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, folks? The reason is that you have ONE unclosed `<a>`-tag in the beginning. Fix that, and the underline between the links goes away.

Answer (score -1):

The `<a></a>` has an underscore by default which is meant to be displayed on the text inside the tag but your `<a></a>` only contains image and no text. You need to remove the text decoration on the anchor tag by saying

```
a{
  text-decoration: none
}
```